# How can i excute code sequentially in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I had a problem. I am writing a method that first checks if the user exists with a condition if not it will insert the action and I am using a flag variable to control the flow. but there is a problem which is the exception is not sequentially instead it goes down tho if(!flag) after that go up to check if the user exists or not

```js
analysis = actionid => {
  //check if it is't the first command
  console.log("before definition of flage");
  var flag = false;
  console.log("hiii");
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("userActions/")
    .once("value", snap => {
      console.log("iafter definition ");
      snap.forEach(child => {
        if (
          child.val().userID === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid &&
          child.val().ActionID == actionid
        ) {
          plus = parseInt(child.val().Repetition) + 1;
          console.log("before first use");
          flag = true;
          firebase
            .database()
            .ref(child)
            .set((Repetition = plus))
            .then(() => {
              console.log("inserted the update");
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
      });
    });

  console.log("before second use");
  if (!flag) {
    console.log("inside second use");
    var userActionKey = firebase
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child("userActions")
      .push().key;
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("userActions/" + userActionKey)
      .set({
        userID: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
        ActionID: "001",
        time: "12",
        Repetition: "1"
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("inserted");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs code synchronously. To solve the problem you can use `promises` or `async-await` to run code async. Or you can just call a function inside your first process.

Below code should work.

```js
function doSomething() {
    var userActionKey =firebase.database().ref().child('userActions').push().key;
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref('userActions/'+userActionKey)
        .set({
            userID:firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
            ActionID:'001',
            time:'12',
            Repetition:'1',
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('inserted')
        }).catch((error)=> {
            console.log(error)
        });
};


firebase.database().ref('userActions/').once ('value',(snap)=>{ 
    snap.forEach((child)=>{
        if(child.val().userID===firebase.auth().currentUser.uid && child.val().ActionID== actionid) {
            plus=parseInt(child.val().Repetition)+1;
            firebase
                .database().ref(child).set(Repetition=plus)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('inserted the update');
                }).catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error);
                }).finally(() => {
                    doSomething();
                });
        }
    });
});
```

I hope the example show you logic here.

I highly recommend you to learn `promises` in JavaScript.